# Should I use the article 'a' here? Or nothing at all?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

Which variant is better?

> We have a chance to get new experience talking to new people.

or

> We have a chance to get **a** new experience talking to new people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one sounds better. But try to express the idea in a different way, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

> We have a chance to get new experience talking to new people.

This means you have a chance to have new experiences in general, to gain experience with new things, *by* talking to new people. It's the same as saying:

> In talking to new people, we have a chance to get new experience.

Whereas:

> We have a chance to get **a** new experience talking to new people.

This can be interpreted as the same as the first, but it has an alternate meaning: you could be saying you have a chance to have a singular, *specific* new experience by talking to some specific new people.

However, these phrasings are a little unusual. Typically we say either *gain experience* or *grow experienced* to refer to the process of becoming experienced in general, while to *have an experience* refers to a specific event. I would rephrase your example to what you most likely meant, the general case:

> We have a chance to gain new experience talking to new people.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of what you are trying to imply.

If you are attempting to gain experience in talking to people (in general), then "... get new experience..."

on the reverse, if you are trying to convey that this is a new opportunity that you have not yet experienced, "... get a new experience..."

Comment: could you give an example, please. What oportunity do you mean?

Comment: when you use the article "A" it implies that this is something unique, as opposed to something more general.  For example: Talking with friends vs talking with *A* friend.  when you say "a" friend, it implies that you focused on one specific friend rather than a general body of friends.  With the provided example in the original post, "get an experience" vs "get experience".  The first implies that this is something unique (you have not experienced this before) where as the second implies that you will gain experience in something you have done before.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use new with experience when using experience to mean "knowledge or practical wisdom".  You can gain valuable experience or more experience but saying "new experience" in this situation is redundant.  You can use new with experience when using it to mean "a particular instance of personally encountering or undergoing something".  For example, "I've seen animals in the wild before, but tripping over an python was definitely a new experience."